# jQuery Mobile icons not showing on Ipad 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ipad, jquery-mobile, retina-display

I am using Andy Matthew's custom jQuery Mobile icon pack (both the "original" and "font-awesome" icons . The font-awesome ones work on the iPad, but the "original" icons do not show up (but show up on Samsung devices etc).

I modified the CSS to work with the Rails asset pipeline as follows:

```
/*
    jQuery Mobile Icon Pack
    andy matthews
    @commadelimited
*/

/* Icons
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.ui-icon,
.ui-icon-searchfield:after {
    background: #666666;
    background:  rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    background-image: image-url('vendor/jqm-icon-pack/icons-18-white-pack.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    border-radius: 9px;
}


/* Alt icon color
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.ui-icon-alt {
    background: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    background-image: image-url('vendor/jqm-icon-pack/icons-18-black-pack.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* restore default loading image */
.ui-icon-loading {
    background: image-url('vendor/jqm-icon-pack/ajax-loader.gif');
    background-size: 46px 46px;
}

/* HD/"retina" sprite
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
        only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
        only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
        only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
        only screen and (min-resolution: 1.3dppx) {

    .ui-icon-plus, .ui-icon-minus, .ui-icon-delete, .ui-icon-arrow-r,
    .ui-icon-arrow-l, .ui-icon-arrow-u, .ui-icon-arrow-d, .ui-icon-check,
    .ui-icon-gear, .ui-icon-refresh, .ui-icon-forward, .ui-icon-back,
    .ui-icon-grid, .ui-icon-star, .ui-icon-alert, .ui-icon-info, .ui-icon-home, .ui-icon-search, .ui-icon-searchfield:after,
    .ui-icon-checkbox-off, .ui-icon-checkbox-on, .ui-icon-radio-off, .ui-icon-radio-on, .ui-icon-email , .ui-icon-page,
    .ui-icon-question , .ui-icon-foursquare , .ui-icon-twitter , .ui-icon-facebook , .ui-icon-dollar , .ui-icon-euro,
    .ui-icon-pound , .ui-icon-apple , .ui-icon-chat , .ui-icon-trash , .ui-icon-bell , .ui-icon-mappin , .ui-icon-direction,
    .ui-icon-heart , .ui-icon-wrench , .ui-icon-play , .ui-icon-pause , .ui-icon-stop , .ui-icon-person , .ui-icon-music,
    .ui-icon-rss , .ui-icon-wifi , .ui-icon-phone , .ui-icon-power , .ui-icon-lock , .ui-icon-flag , .ui-icon-calendar,
    .ui-icon-lightning , .ui-icon-drink , .ui-icon-android , .ui-icon-edit {
        background-image: image-url('vendor/jqm-icon-pack/icons-36-white-pack.png');
        -moz-background-size: 774px 54px;
        -o-background-size: 774px 54px;
        -webkit-background-size: 774px 54px;
        background-size: 774px 54px;
    }
    .ui-icon-alt {
        background-image: image-url('vendor/jqm-icon-pack/icons-36-black-pack.png');
    }
}
```

Other than that I have made no changes. The images directory looks like this: assets/images/vendor/jqm-icon-pack

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453714/why-arent-jquery-mobile-icons-clipped-properly-in-high-resolution-devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery Mobile serves up Retina optimised icons, but at the time there was a bug in the logic for displaying Retina friendly icons